# Can I use macro var to get ID?

Tags: android

Normally, we use R.String.btnClose to get a ID.
Sometings, I hope to use the following code to ID, I know the code is wrong.
I don't know if java support macro var, if so, how can I write code? Thanks!

String s="btnClose"
R.string.s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try [`Resources.getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

An equivalent for

```
int id = R.string.btnClose;
```

would be

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("btnClose", "string", getPackageName());
```

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

For example you could have a `Map<String, Integer>` which returns your id from name.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of activity use this :

```
String s = getString(R.string.btnClose );
```

Not in Activity :

```
public String getText(Context context, int resourceId)
{
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    return resources.getString(resourceId);
}
```